# Can't import opencv in Python 2.7: ImportError: No module named cv2 despite installed opencv 3.2.0

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

I used `brew` to install opencv 3.2.0 and it seems successful to me. Yet module `cv2` still cannot be found when I tried to run this:

```
FF-MBP:read_video_frames ff$ python v2f.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "v2f.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

The `brew` installation looks like this:

```
FF-MBP:read_video_frames ff$ brew install opencv3
==> Installing opencv3 from homebrew/science
==> Installing dependencies for homebrew/science/opencv3: eigen, jpeg, libpng, libtiff, ilmbase, openexr
==> Installing homebrew/science/opencv3 dependency: eigen
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/eigen-3.3.4.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring eigen-3.3.4.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Using the sandbox
  /usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.3.4: 486 files, 6.5MB
==> Installing homebrew/science/opencv3 dependency: jpeg
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/jpeg-8d.sierra.bottle.2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring jpeg-8d.sierra.bottle.2.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d: 19 files, 708.3KB
==> Installing homebrew/science/opencv3 dependency: libpng
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libpng-1.6.29.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring libpng-1.6.29.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/1.6.29: 26 files, 1.2MB
==> Installing homebrew/science/opencv3 dependency: libtiff
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libtiff-4.0.8.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring libtiff-4.0.8.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/libtiff/4.0.8: 245 files, 3.4MB
==> Installing homebrew/science/opencv3 dependency: ilmbase
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/ilmbase-2.2.0.sierra.bottle.2.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring ilmbase-2.2.0.sierra.bottle.2.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/ilmbase/2.2.0: 362 files, 5.6MB
==> Installing homebrew/science/opencv3 dependency: openexr
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/openexr-2.2.0.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring openexr-2.2.0.sierra.bottle.1.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/openexr/2.2.0: 131 files, 11.2MB
==> Installing homebrew/science/opencv3
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-science/opencv3-3.2.0.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring opencv3-3.2.0.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because opencv3 and opencv install many of the same files.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/opencv3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/opencv3/include


If you need Python to find bindings for this keg-only formula, run:
  echo /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages >> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/opencv3.pth
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/3.2.0: 286 files, 47.4MB
```

Is it because `opencv 3.0+` only compiles with `Python3.x`? I tried `import cv3` - doesn't work. 
Appreciate any inputs. Thank you!

Mac OS X: Sierra 10.12.5

Python: 2.7

OpenCV: 3.2.0

Comment: Read carefully the warnings/Instructions after `Caveats`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install` to install opencv in windows. To install first go to cmd. Browse to opencv in cmd. `pip install opencv` to install it.

Comment: Except this is not a Windows install, but for MacOS.

Comment: @JohanL `pip install` works on MacOS exactly the same way.

Comment: @phd It does, and perhaps I should have been more explicit in my remark, that the question was about an issue about `brew install` on MacOS.

Comment: @JohanL @phd Thank you both for the reply. Yes the question is about `brew`. I'm suspecting if `brew` installed opencv 3.2.0 to a different directory than other Python packages'. My other packages are located at `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` but I don't find an `opencv` folder under that directory.

Comment: Also this is what I tried `pip install`:

`FF-MBP:read_video_frames ff$ pip install opencv
Collecting opencv
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for opencv`

Comment: You havent installed it correctly yet.. Sometimes its seems you have installed but it is not installed. Have you checked out environment variables ???

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is solved! I managed to get it correctly installed on PyCharm. Tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#d64763e97